# Où trouver des livres audio (audiobooks) non romanesques et contemporains ?

Tags: ressources, oral

J'aimerais savoir où je puis acquérir, à titre gracieux, des livres audio non romanesques <s>et modernes</s>  écrits en français, ou traduits en français, ceux qui sont forcément publiés pendant les 50 ans derniers.

En plus de livres, je m’intéresse à des magazines tels que *Psychologies* et (des traductions) de *Psychology Today* ou *Scientific American*.

Google ne m'a montré que des œuvres classiques et des sites Web comme :

- [French.about.com](http://french.about.com/od/audiobooks/)
- [Uk.answers.yahoo.com](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110810091500AAmw0TV)
- [Litteratureaudio.com](http://www.litteratureaudio.com/)

Comment: En France, la plupart des médiathèques ont un fonds de livres audio. Ça ne coûte que le prix de l'inscription. La majorité de ces livres est en français, mais quelques uns sont dans d'autres langues. J'imagine que les médiathèques hors de France disposent aussi d'un fonds de livres audio en français. En revanche, je doute que les périodiques soient disponibles sous cette forme.

Comment: Dans le même genre que les livres audio, je trouve que les podcasts sont un bon moyen de pratiquer. Il en existe plusieurs sur la psychologie et d'autres sur les sciences en général - moins qu'en langue anglaise, certes.

Comment: @guillaume31: Merci. Pourriez-vous spécifier où ou me fournir les liens ?

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, je vous conseille le site http://www.astread.com créé par deux développeurs français.

Le système permet de convertir n'importe quel livre électronique en livre audio. La transcription est assez fidèle même si la voix tien plus du GPS que de l'humain, mais honnêtement c'est très correct. Surtout que c'est gratuit.

En plus, si vous n'avez pas de livre électronique, il y a un catalogues de 1200 livres convertibles directement en audio en seulement quelques clicks. Franchement, il ne manque plus qu'une application mobile relié à tout ça, et c'est le trop :p

Answer (score 0):

Il existe de nombreuses bibliothèques de livres auditifs. Cela dit, fais attention à ce que tu entends par *moderne* car il s’agit d’un faux-ami avec l’anglais *modern*. Dans la littérature française la Modernité s’arrête approximativement en 1850 (selon les auteurs) et à partir de là commence l’aire contemporaine. Alors que l’anglais appelle *modern* ce que nous distinguons entre modernité et aire contemporaine.

Si donc tu souhaites des ouvrages *modernes* stricto sensu, je ne puis que trop te conseiller :

- [Audiocite](http://www.audiocite.net/) ;
- [Bibliboom](http://www.bibliboom.com/) ;
- [La Bibliothèque sonore des Donneurs de voie](http://www.advbs.fr/) ;
- [Audiolivres](https://audiolivres.wordpress.com/category/audiolivres/) ;
- l’[*Internet Archive*](https://archive.org/details/AuFilDesLectures) ;
- [Livres audio](http://www.litteratureaudio.com/livres-audio-gratuits-sur-internet).

Si par *moderne* vous entendiez *contemporain*, je ne connais que la forge littéraire libre [Atramenta](http://www.atramenta.net/) qui fournit quelques fois des livres audio, (elle n’y est pas spécialisée).

Comment: +1. Merci de votre avertissement au sujet du faux ami !

Comment: Note à moi-même : Le lien sur Atramenta est http://www.atramenta.net/audiobooks?sort=popularity

Answer (score 0):

L'application LibriVox contient de nombreux enregistrements autant en français qu'en anglais.

L'application de baladodiffusion"Podcast Addict" contient plusieurs balados portant sur une panoplie de sujets.

Comment: Merci, mais où sont ceux non-romanesques et contemporains sur LibriVox ? Sur https://librivox.org/search?primary_key=2&search_category=language&search_page=11&search_form=get_results, je ne vois que les livres romanesques et vieux.

Answer (score -1):

Il existe aussi http://www.raudiobook.com c'est en ligne en francais et facile d'utilisation à ecouter. Il y a une section sciences.